# stsadm -o import error

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to import a sharepoint site and have got the following error.

Error: Unable to update the information in the Microsoft Office document (doc name with relative url)

This is a MOSS 2007 site collection. Exported from one server farm and trying to import to an "identical" but different server farm. The exact cmd I am running is as follows

stsadm -o import -url (http://webaddress) -filename (path to .cmp file) -includeusersecurity -haltonfatalerror -updateversions 2

How do I fix this?

Update (10 June 2010): I tried deleting the doc file from the source site with the intension of exporting without it but it would not let me delete it! Any spark?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error if you have files greater than 5 MB in the source site you exported.

If the file sizes don't seem to be an issue, try using the `-nofilecompression` option on both your export and import to see if that gets around your problem.

Comment: Tried this but no improvement. I have also tried moving the SQL data file to a different drive where there is more space. The original one was under c: and nearing max capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an issue related to blocked file extensions but since you say this is an office document I guess that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: There are other .doc files that worked but just this one file seems to be an issue. I have also seen the size of the file. Although it is big ~6 MB there are other bigger files that have gone through